# Flutter: "Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build." when trying to call setState() on a page behind the current route

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an interesting setup.

I have a class which extends `State` and gives me some extra functionality. In this class I have an `isLoading` variable which allows me to display a `CircularProgressIndicator` in any instance of this state.

I have a class which performs an API request to the server for data and while it's doing that, it uses a controller class to set `isLoading` to true in any applicable widgets to show that it's loading data.

The problem is, when I load a new page and then the API handler updates the `isLoading` parameter and the `ConvenienceState` class runs `setState()`, I get the error happening on the now hidden page, but I'm not exactly sure why it's happening. Does the page behind the current route have to rebuild in an inconvenient manner? How do I remedy this issue?

Here's a working bug example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bug example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Bug Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends ConvenienceState<MyHomePage> {

  MyHomePageState(){
    API.getData();
  }

// It doesn't work when API.getData() is here instead, either
//  @override
//  void initState() {
//    super.initState();
//    API.getData();
//  }


  @override
  Widget buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context){
                    return NextPage();
                  }
                )
              );
            },
            child: Text("Next Page"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return NextPageState();
  }

}

class NextPageState extends ConvenienceState<NextPage>{
  NextPageState(){
    API.getData();
  }

// It doesn't work when API.getData() is here instead, either
//  @override
//  void initState() {
//    super.initState();
//    API.getData();
//  }

  @override
  Widget buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("NextPage"),),
      body: Center(child: Text("Content"),),
    );
  }

}

class API {
  static Future<bool> getData()async{
    RemoteController.update("loading");
    return await Future<bool>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3),(){
      RemoteController.update("notLoading");
      return true;
    });
  }
}

class RemoteController {
  static List<Function(String)> listeners = [];
  static void update(String type) {
    listeners.forEach((Function listener) {
      listener(type);
    });
  }

  static void addListener(Function(String) listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }

  static void removeListener(Function(String) listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
  }
}

abstract class ConvenienceState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State{
  T get widget {
    return super.widget;
  }
  /// Keeps track of whether or not the page is built (ready for [setState()])
  bool isBuilt = false;

  bool _isLoading = false;

  /// Determines if the loading screen is displayed
  set isLoading(bool value){
    _isLoading = value;
    if(mounted && isBuilt)
      setState(() {});
  }
  /// Determines if the loading screen is displayed
  get isLoading{
    return _isLoading;
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      isBuilt = true;
    });

    RemoteController.addListener(rcListener);
  }
  void rcListener(String type) {
    if(type=="loading"){
      isLoading = true;
    }
    if(type=="notLoading"){
      isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  dispose(){
    RemoteController.removeListener(rcListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget buildContent(BuildContext context);

  @override
  build(BuildContext context){
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        buildContent(context),
        Visibility(
          visible: isLoading,
          child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When you click the "NextPage" button, the error shows up, referring to the `MyHomePage` class.

Comment: Are you sure that `MyHomePage` is gettings disposed and thus has removed the listener from the `RemoteController`?

Comment: I didn't think it's getting disposed as I thought new routes get pushed in front of old routes without disposing them. Do they get disposed in that case? I was under the impression they stayed until popped.

Comment: Then this might be your problem (although i am very unsure): Your invisible route still gets the rcListener call because of the Api.getData() call from `NextPageState` and at this point it is no longer built. I am just guessing tho.

Comment: That may be it. I figured it would say that I can't call it after it's been disposed in that case. I did find, shortly after posting the question, that checking `ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent` before calling `setState()` does solve it. It's a strange issue that I don't understand. It says that the widget is currently building is the reason, but I would think it would have already been built (unless the entire route gets built again but then I would imagine both routes would have the issue).